# patched operators to pipable operators, angular 5 to 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am migrating from angular 5 to 6 and I can't quite figure out the new pipeable operator syntax.

Consider my angular 5 http interceptor

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.request = req;

//do stuff
return next.handle(this.request)
  .do(event => {

   //do logging stuff
  },
  err => {
    //do error stuff
  });
}
```

Here is my attempt in converting this to the `pipe` way

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.request = req;

//do stuff
return next.handle(this.request).pipe(
  tap(event => {

   //do logging stuff
  },
  err => {
    //do error stuff
  }));
}
```

This doesn't compile however - the whole thing withing the `pipe` function is underlined with the following error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2345  (TS) Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<{}>' is not 
assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<HttpEvent<any>>, 
Observable<any>>'.
Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>' is not assignable to type 
'Observable<{}>'.
  Property 'source' is protected in type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>' but public in type 'Observable<{}>'.  C:\Users\stas.levich\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project) C:\Users\stas.levich\Documents\Projects\EEA.Projects\DEP\MassAir\Web\src\app\services\httpinterceptor.service.ts    44  Active
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pipe` requires a set of operators. The `tap` is an operator. The  `err =>` function is *not* a valid RxJs operator. Try `catchError`

Here is an example of one of my get methods:

```
 getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.moviesUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Comment: I took it a step further and just simplified this to the most basics `return next.handle(this.request).pipe(tap(event => { console.log("hey") }));`. Still the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
        tap(event => {
            return event;
        }),
        catchError(error => {

            // On Error
        }),
        finalize(() => {
         // on finalize
        })
    );
```